# Core for Neumann Laplacians

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis

Let $d$ be a positive integer. We write $\mathbb{H}^d$ for the closed $d$-dimensional upper-half space: $\mathbb{H}^d=\{(x_1,\ldots,x_d) \in \mathbb{R}^d,\,x_d \ge 0\}$.  We consider the Neumann semigroup $\{T_t\}_{t>0}$ on $C_{0}(\mathbb{H}^d)$. Here, $C_{0}(\mathbb{H}^d)$ is the space of continuous functions on $\mathbb{H}^d$ vanishing at infinity.

In other words, $\{T_t\}_{t>0}$ is the semigroup of the normally reflected Brownian motion on $\mathbb{H}^d$. Let $(L,D(L))$ be the generator of $\{T_t\}_{t>0}$ (Neumann Laplacian on $\mathbb{H}^d$). That is,
\begin{align*}
D(L)&=\left\{f \in C_0(\mathbb{H}^d) : \lim_{t \to 0}\frac{T_tf-f}{t} \text{ exists in }C_0(\mathbb{H}^d) \right\},\\
Lf&=\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{T_tf-f}{t},\quad f \in D(L).
\end{align*}
Let $\nu$ be the inward unit normal vector on $\partial \mathbb{H}^d$, the boundary of $\mathbb{H}^d$. We set
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{C}&=\{f \in C^2(\mathbb{R}^d) \mid \langle \nabla f(x),\, \nu(x) \rangle=0\text{ for every }x\in \partial \mathbb{H}^d \}, \\
\mathcal{C}'&=\{f \in C^2(\mathbb{R}^d) \mid \langle \nabla f(x),\, \nu(x) \rangle= \langle\nu(x) \nabla^2 f(x),\, \nu(x) \rangle=0\text{ for every }x\in \partial \mathbb{H}^d \}.
\end{align*}
It is known that $\mathcal{C}$ is a core for the Neumann Laplacian $(L,D(L))$.　Is $\mathcal{C}'$ also a core?

Comment: This is not true for $d=1$, that is in the half-line. In this case the domain consists of all $C^2$ functions with vanishing first derivatives at $0$ and those with vanishing first and second derivatives at $0$ are a closed subspace of the domain.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune Thank you for your reply. Do you mean that $\mathcal{C}$ is not a core for the Neumann Laplacian if $d=1$? Am I making a mistake?

Comment: No, I mean that $\mathcal C'$ is not a core. For $d=1$ your $\mathcal C$ is equal to the domain.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune Oh, I understand. Thank you. Then, even in the case of $d>1$, $\mathcal{C}'$ is not a core.